# Optaplanner - Drools rules List<> memberOf List<>?

Tags: java, drools, optaplanner

I'm enjoying a journey through Optaplanner. Java isn't my "native" language but to my surprise the (steep?) learning curve of Optaplanner & Drools hasn't driven me to giving up!

What I've got so far:
I've made a project with the necessary classes. For the sake of my question, I'll simplify to: an `Employee` class, a `Job` class, a `Skills` class and the `Schedule` class, where I'd like to get my perfect Optaplanned schedule.

My employees class has a variable `List<Skill> skills` containing at least 1 skill they have.
My job class contains the same variable `List<Skill> reqSkills` (req = required). This contains at least 1 skill necessary to be able to do this job.

I've initialized with some dummy data. Then I run the following rule:

```
rule "requiredSkills"
    when
        Employee($skills : skills)
        Job(reqskills not memberOf $skills)
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -1);
end
```

I thought (but here the steep curve for Drools is beating me) this seemed logical: when an employee's skill is not a member of the skill(s) necessary for the job then that's a hard constraint..

The result for my "planning" is always: the first employee that I've put in as dummy data is linked to all jobs...

My feeling is that using `memberOf` does not work for lists vs lists. But how do I fix this, as both my employees as my jobs might have/require multiple skills?

Comment: PS: ConstraintStreams, coming in a future version, should lower the learning curve.

Comment: Thanks: look forward to that. For the record: I can live with a steep learning curve. It's more impatience to see the result of Optaplanner used in my project!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never use the drools construct `not memberOf` in OptaPlanner cases. Maybe because of habit, maybe because it slow or brittle).

FWIW, this is very similar to [the skill requirement in optaweb-employee-rostering](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaweb-employee-rostering/blob/master/employee-rostering-server/src/main/resources/org/optaweb/employeerostering/server/solver/employeeRosteringScoreRules.drl#L39) which just uses plain java code constructs inside the `Shift` DRL pattern:

```
rule "Required skill for a shift"
    when
        Shift(
                employee != null,
                !getEmployee().hasSkills(getSpot().getRequiredSkillSet()))
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -100);
end
```

Comment: Okay. Using plain java code was an eye-opener. However, what I don't get from the example is the use of `Shift(`... In my case that should be Schedule, but I don't have an Employee in it, but a List<Employee>. Sorry, might just be real stupid remark.. Just not seen the light yet...

`!getEmployee().hasSkills(getSpot().getRequiredSkillSet()))`is a line I can't retrace in the source..

Comment: I made my rule as follows, but not the expected result, so closer but not there yet:
`rule "requiredSkills"
    when

      Job($reqskills : reqskills)
        Employee(
              !hasSkillset($reqskills)
        )
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -100);
end`

Comment: You'll want to match the employee assigned to that job.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I got it working. Fingers crossed I can keep moving on now! Thanks for the support!!